# Make a VPN Connection from Azure VM

Tags: database, azure, flask, vpn, checkpoint

I am developing a Flask application for a company and it is going to be deployed on Azure VM. The app needs to make a vpn connection to access the database of the company. Is there a way of making such connection from Azure VM? VPN : Checkpoint. I mean, the question is that, Can I make a VPN connection from  Azure VM for an application that needs to access to the database in a secured network and how?

Thank you,

Comment: Simple answer: yes, you can. It should not really be much different than from any other server. What is preventing you from doing so? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Site-to-Site VPN gateway connection.

A Site-to-Site VPN gateway connection is used to connect your on-premises network to an Azure virtual network over an IPsec/IKE (IKEv1 or IKEv2) VPN tunnel. Then the application on the Azure VM can communicate with its on-premise database with its private IP address.

On the Azure side, you need to create a Virtual Network(Azure VM located), Virtual network gateway, Local network gateway (typically refers to your on-premises location) and configure your VPN device. Read [Create a Site-to-Site connection in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal)

You could also read [validated VPN devices and device configuration guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices#devicetable). Follow the [PolicyBased configuration instructions](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk101275) or [RouteBased configuration instructions](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk101275) for Check Point to configure your on-premise network.