# Connect from Azure Windows VM (Windows Server 2012) to VPN using built-in VPN client

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn, windows-server-2012, azure-vpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN from a Windows VM on Azure and cannot do so. I am using the built-in Windows VPN Client.

I am connecting to this VPN in order to be able to access a server within that VPN and send and receive HTTP Requests.

I have been able to connect to this VPN normally on other devices using the built-in Windows VPN Client. I followed the exact same steps for the VM but receive the following error when trying to connect:

**Error 800:The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an L2TP/IPsec tunnel, the security parameters required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured properly**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x59hs.png)

I have also opened ports 1723,1701,500,47,4500 in Azure portal for both inbound and outbound on the Azure Portal (screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awW6X.png))

I have also tried the steps described in this post:

[Make a VPN Connection from Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549591/make-a-vpn-connection-from-azure-vm/60557916)

But does not do what I want. I have the VPN's public IP and username/password, and nowhere does the above mention how to set this up.

Do I need any additional settings or open any other ports in order for this to work?

Comment: Do you set up point to site VPN connection from your Azure VPN client?

Comment: I did not @NancyXiong. Should I follow this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about

Comment: You can follow that, but want to know what you have done about configuring a VPN connection when you said "I have been able to connect to this VPN normally on other devices using the built-in Windows VPN Client."?

Comment: I followed these steps in both my Windows 10 Machine and Azure VM to create a VPN profile: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows-10-3d29aeb1-f497-f6b7-7633-115722c1009c

Comment: What's the VPN server? Do you have deployed a virtual network gateway and site-to-site VPN connection in Azure?

Comment: Yes I have. I have created a Virtual Network, a VPN gateway and Local Network Gateway. I have followed these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal however the VPN connection status was showing as "Unknown" in Azure Portal.

Comment: Do you have any VPN devices? Do you want to connect from Azure VM to the on-premise network?

Comment: That is correct. The VPN is on-premises, and I want to join the Azure VM in that VPN, so I can send HTTP requests from the Azure VM to a server located within that VPN

Comment: If you have set up the site-to-site VPN connection well, the VPN connection status is "connected", you should have connected on both sides. So you should diagnose the VPN connection and refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-disconnected-intermittently).

Comment: Thank you @NancyXiong I will check all of these troubleshooting steps you have suggested. I would have expected this to be a more straightforward task as it was for my local Windows 10 machine. I will try these and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it seems that you want to connect Azure VM to a server on your on-premise network with your local VPN device.

In this case, you could set up a site-to-site VPN connection to connect the Azure VNet and on-premise network following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

After that, you can directly connect to your Azure VM with its private IP address from your on-premise server. In fact, you don't need to connect from Azure Windows VM (Windows Server 2012) to VPN using a built-in VPN client because once the VPN is connected, the traffic from the on-premise network to the Azure network goes through the VPN tunnel and vice versa. We don't need to connect from Azure VM just from on-premise resources.

Comment: Thank you for this Doris, these are the steps that I had already followed as mentioned above and also pointed out by @NancyXiong. I followed all the steps on my end and it seems that the organization that has the server and VPN Device needs to do some extra configuration. I just expected it to be as easy to connect to the VPN as it would be using any standard Windows device